# My JSP gets error while inserting data into mysql databse

Tags: mysql, jsp

I receive the following error:

> com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column
>   'gender' in 'field list'  at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:936)     at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:2985)    at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:1631)     at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:1723)  at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.execSQL(Connection.java:3250)   at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.Statement.executeUpdate(Statement.java:1355)   at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.Statement.executeUpdate(Statement.java:1270)   at
>   org.apache.jsp.reg_jsp._jspService(reg_jsp.java:157)  at
>   org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)    at
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)  at
>   org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:438)
>     at
>   org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:396)
>     at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:340)
>     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:217)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:518)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1091)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:673)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1500)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1456)
>     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
>     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) not
>   insertedcom.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown
>   column 'gender' in 'field list'

From this code:

```
String fname=request.getParameter("firstnm"); 
String lnames=request.getParameter("lname"); 
String gen=request.getParameter("ddlGender"); 
String mail=request.getParameter("txtMailID"); 
String mobile=request.getParameter("txtMobilenumber"); 
String pass1=request.getParameter("txtPass"); 
String pass2=request.getParameter("txtPass1"); 
Integer tim=Integer.parseInt(mobile); 
Integer passw=Integer.parseInt(pass1); 
Integer passw2=Integer.parseInt(pass2);

String query="INSERT INTO register (firstname, lastname, gender, email, mobile, password1, password2) VALUES('"+fname+"','"+lnames+"','"+gen+"','"+mail+"','"+tim+‌​"','"+passw+"','"+pa‌​ssw2+"')"; 
try { 
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
    cons=DriverManager.getConnection(conurl,conuname,conpass);
    stmt=cons.createStatement();
    stmt.executeUpdate(query);
    System.out.println("inserted");
    cons.close(); 
} catch(Exception ex){ 
    ex.printStackTrace(); 
    System.out.println("not inserted"+ex); 
}
```

Comment: code? Your problem seems very simple

Comment: String fname=request.getParameter("firstnm");
String lnames=request.getParameter("lname");
String gen=request.getParameter("ddlGender");
String mail=request.getParameter("txtMailID");
String mobile=request.getParameter("txtMobilenumber");
String pass1=request.getParameter("txtPass");
String pass2=request.getParameter("txtPass1");
Integer tim=Integer.parseInt(mobile);
Integer passw=Integer.parseInt(pass1);
Integer passw2=Integer.parseInt(pass2);

Comment: String query="INSERT INTO `register` (`firstname`, `lastname`, `gender`, `email`, `mobile`, `password1`, `password2`) VALUES('"+fname+"','"+lnames+"','"+gen+"','"+mail+"','"+tim+"','"+passw+"','"+passw2+"')";
try
{
 Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
 cons=DriverManager.getConnection(conurl,conuname,conpass);
 stmt=cons.createStatement();
 stmt.executeUpdate(query);
 System.out.println("inserted");
 
 cons.close();
}
catch(Exception ex){
 ex.printStackTrace();
 System.out.println("not inserted"+ex);
}

Comment: Unknown column 'gender' in database?

Comment: Query is builded in wrong way, with '+ string'. Use SQL parameters.

Comment: Formatted code should be in question, not comment.

Comment: Use PreparedStatement !! I could drop the table if you did not manage the user rights correctly...

Answer (score 0):

There appears to be a small problem in your code.
You can not use `"+VARIABLE_NAME+"` to insert Integer datatype in your database, it is only applicable for String datatype. Instead to insert Integer drop single inverted quotation marks and use `"+VARIABLE_NAME+"` only.

Modify your SQL query to,

```
String query="INSERT INTO register (firstname, lastname, gender, email, mobile, password1, password2) 
   VALUES('"+fname+"','"+lnames+"','"+gen+"','"+mail+"',"+tim+‌​","+passw+","+pa‌​ssw2+")";
```